# Why this method is wrong?

Tags: java

This question is more like puzzle rather than real question,

what is wrong with this method:

```
public boolean areEqual(Long a, long b)
{
return a==b;
}
```

Comment: nothing...........................................

Comment: Is there a known solution to your puzzle you will give us or is it just to check that the SO community knows the boxing/unboxing mechanism ?

Comment: hèhè, how to get a gazillion (same) answers to a question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with it, apart from the fact that it can throw a `NullPointerException` if `a` is `null` (the auto-unboxing will throw a NPE).

Comment: Damn, beat me to it by 30 seconds! :P

Comment: same here ! that's why he has 49k and us < 10k ;)

Comment: @JeromeC. A lot of practice ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It depends...

For instance, if you pass null as the first argument (which you can), you'll get a `NullPointerException`, since `toLongValue` will be called on the object.

Answer (score 0):

due to automatic boxing / unboxing

nothing is wrong in this method (well, only if `a` is null, it can throw a NPE)...

BUT if wrong means bad practice, well you are not using a good indentation and do not follow the java coding convention (parenthesis on the first line)

Answer (score 0):

Long a should be a pointer to a long value

long b should be a long value

so if you test equal you test a pointer (value) vs a long value

Comment: There are no pointers in Java

Comment: there are pointers in java, everything is a pointer except int, etc

Comment: jan = new Class(); 
jan is now a pointer to class Class'.
int i = 10;
i is now a value of ten.

Comment: No. `jan` is a reference to an instance of `Class`. `Java != C++`.

Comment: reference is a pointer.

Comment: [Not exactly](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer).

Comment: "Java doesn't have pointers."

Answer (score 0):

Your a value can be null (Long type) and b can not be (long type)
Therefore a==b will cause nullpointer when a==null.